# How to label boxes created on JavaScript canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, json, canvas

I have a canvas where I can draw boxes, and then save the x-y coordinates and width and height of these boxes into JSON format. However, I would like to know if it's possible to perhaps have a field where I can enter a unique name for each one of these objects (eg. bluecar, redcar etc.), in which the name will also appear in the JSON output? As shown in the JSON output below, the coordinates and other information are appearing correctly but I'd like to include names for the objects to differentiate them between the other objects.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
let isDrawing = false;

const annotation = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  w: 0,
  h: 0,
  printCoordinates: function() {
    console.log(`X: ${this.x}px, Y: ${this.y}px, Width: ${this.w}px, Height: ${this.h}px`);
  }
};

let boundingBoxes = [];

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  start = oMousePos(canvas2, e);
  isDrawing = true;
  //console.log(start.x, start.y);
  canvas2.style.cursor = "crosshair";
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    m = oMousePos(canvas2, e);
    draw();
  }
}


function handleMouseUp(e) {
  canvas2.style.cursor = "default";
  isDrawing = false;

  const box = Object.create(annotation);
  box.x = o.x;
  box.y = o.y;
  box.w = o.w;
  box.h = o.h;

  boundingBoxes.push(box);
  draw();
  box.printCoordinates();
  console.log(boundingBoxes)
}

canvas2.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

canvas2.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

canvas2.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

function draw() {
  o.x = start.x; // start position of x
  o.y = start.y; // start position of y
  o.w = m.x - start.x; // width
  o.h = m.y - start.y; // height

  context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height); //////***********
  // draw all the rectangles saved in the rectsRy
  boundingBoxes.map(r => {
    drawRect(r)
  })
  // draw the actual rectangle
  drawRect(o);
}

function drawRect(o) {
  context2.strokeStyle = "limegreen";
  context2.lineWidth = 2;
  context2.beginPath(o);
  context2.rect(o.x, o.y, o.w, o.h);
  context2.stroke();
}

function oMousePos(canvas2, evt) {
  let ClientRect = canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // retrieve the canvas data
  var canvasContents = canvas.toDataURL(); // a data URL of the current
  // canvas

  var string = JSON.stringify(boundingBoxes, null, 2);

  // create a blob object representing the data as a JSON string
  var file = new Blob([string], {
    type: 'application/json'
  });

  // trigger a click event on an <a> tag to open the file explorer
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = 'data.json';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  Import Image: <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" multiple/>

  <p>
    <div id="buttons1">
      <button id="reset" onclick="resetcanvas()">Reset Annotations</button> &nbsp
      <button id="save">
       <span>Export Annotations</span>
      </button>

      <div id="canvases" align="middle" style="position:relative; width:1580px; height:700px; overflow: scroll; ">
        <canvas id="canvas2" align="middle" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 125px; top: 0px; "></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" align="middle" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 125px; top: 0px; "></canvas>
      </div>

      <p></p>
      <br>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="button ">

    </div>
```

JSON Output:

```
[
  {
    "x": 356,
    "y": 235,
    "w": -105,
    "h": -146
  },
  {
    "x": 185,
    "y": 238,
    "w": -51,
    "h": -93
  }
]
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Your code shows error: Uncaught ReferenceError: o is not defined...

Answer (score 0):

I added a few variables to bypass your errors... I assumed that was just a copy/paste error.

On the `handleMouseUp` you can add a `box.name = "Name";` to include a name

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var context2 = canvas2.getContext('2d');
let isDrawing = false;

const annotation = {
  x: 0, y: 0, w: 0, h: 0,
  printCoordinates: function() {
    console.log(`X: ${this.x}px, Y: ${this.y}px, Width: ${this.w}px, Height: ${this.h}px`);
  }
};

var o = annotation;
var start;

let boundingBoxes = [];

function handleMouseUp(e) {
  canvas2.style.cursor = "default";
  isDrawing = false;

  const box = Object.create(annotation);
  box.x = o.x;
  box.y = o.y;
  box.w = o.w;
  box.h = o.h;
  box.name = "Name";

  boundingBoxes.push(box);
  draw();
  box.printCoordinates();
  //console.log(boundingBoxes)
}

function handleMouseDown(e) {
  start = oMousePos(canvas2, e);
  isDrawing = true;
  //console.log(start.x, start.y);
  canvas2.style.cursor = "crosshair";
}

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    m = oMousePos(canvas2, e);
    draw();
  }
}

canvas2.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown);

canvas2.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMouseMove);

canvas2.addEventListener("mouseup", handleMouseUp);

function draw() {
  o.x = start.x; // start position of x
  o.y = start.y; // start position of y
  o.w = m.x - start.x; // width
  o.h = m.y - start.y; // height

  context2.clearRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height); //////***********
  // draw all the rectangles saved in the rectsRy
  boundingBoxes.map(r => {
    drawRect(r)
  })
  // draw the actual rectangle
  drawRect(o);
}

function drawRect(o) {
  context2.strokeStyle = "limegreen";
  context2.lineWidth = 2;
  context2.beginPath(o);
  context2.rect(o.x, o.y, o.w, o.h);
  context2.stroke();
}

function oMousePos(canvas2, evt) {
  let ClientRect = canvas2.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: Math.round(evt.clientX - ClientRect.left),
    y: Math.round(evt.clientY - ClientRect.top)
  }
}

document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // retrieve the canvas data
  var canvasContents = canvas.toDataURL(); // a data URL of the current
  // canvas

  var string = JSON.stringify(boundingBoxes, null, 2);

  // create a blob object representing the data as a JSON string
  var file = new Blob([string], {
    type: 'application/json'
  });

  // trigger a click event on an <a> tag to open the file explorer
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = 'data.json';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  Import Image: <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" multiple/>

  <p>
    <div id="buttons1">
      <button id="reset" onclick="resetcanvas()">Reset Annotations</button> &nbsp
      <button id="save"><span>Export Annotations</span></button>

      <div id="canvases" align="middle" style="position:relative; width:1580px; height:700px; overflow: scroll; ">
        <canvas id="canvas2" align="middle" style="z-index: 1; position: absolute; left: 125px; top: 0px; "></canvas>
        <canvas id="canvas" align="middle" style="z-index: 0; position: absolute; left: 125px; top: 0px; "></canvas>
      </div>

      <p></p>
      <br>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <div id="button ">

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) However, how should I input the name then? Should I create a text field or something?